# ImportError: No module named taggit.managers

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the django-inline-media for my blog project such that I can put images in between sections of my blog posts. I am however running into some problems following the tutorial at https://django-inline-media.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

The installation process is fine and following the configuration steps are ok until step 3 where it say to run the following

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I then run into the error `ImportError: No module named taggit.managers`. I get this error for both commands.

I don't have any luck searching on that error so I'm hoping someone will be able to help. Also, if you think there is an alternative way or a better way for me to achieve this with Django do let me know.

Comment: show your `INSTALLED_APPS` section

Comment: # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles',
    'inline_media',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'tagging'
]

THUMBNAIL_BACKEND = "inline_media.sorl_backends.AutoFormatBackend"
THUMBNAIL_FORMAT = "JPEG"

Comment: also show `pip freeze | grep sorl` and `pip freeze | grep tagging`

Comment: sorl-thumbnail==12.5.0

Comment: And tagging==0.2.1

Comment: The problem seems to be with the 'inline_media' in INSTALLED APPS. If I remove that from the INSTALLED_APPS the error goes away, but without it I won't be able to do what I want

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

```
pip install django-taggit
```